# The store was last opened on a different machine

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

When I disconnect my computer form my docking station where it is on wired internet and connect to wifi (automatically done) Outlook 2010 hangs and needs to be restarted. The same error happens in reverse; wifi --> wired connection.

There is an error in the event viewer after Outlook restarts with the message

> Starting reconciliation for the store C:\Users\me\Documents\Outlook Files\archive.pst for the following reason: The store was last opened on a different machine.
>
> Event ID 30.

archive.pst is about 300 MB.

This happens maybe about half the time I make the wifi-->wired/wired-->wifi transition. The "solution" at the moment is to restart Outlook.

How can I stop this from happening?